# iOS 11 and up crashing with -[UIView setDrawsWithVibrantLightMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I've noticed a significant spike in app crashes on iOS 11 and up with this message. This appears to be an internal API that `UIKit` is calling, the stack trace reveals that it's something inside `UITableViewCell`:

```
    Application Specific Information:
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setDrawsWithVibrantLightMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15defa6d0'

    Last Exception Backtrace:
    0   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000181691d04 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x00000001808e0528 objc_exception_throw + 52
    2   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018169f1c8 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 136
    3   UIKit                                0x000000018ae8711c -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 292
    4   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001816976b0 ___forwarding___ + 1376
    5   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018157d01c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 88
    6   UIKit                                0x000000018b022d58 -[UITableViewCell _setSeparatorDrawsInVibrantLightMode:] + 216
    7   UIKit                                0x000000018abf5ef0 -[UITableViewCell setSeparatorColor:] + 340
    8   UIKit                                0x000000018abf451c __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 1228
    9   UIKit                                0x000000018aad6e34 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 100
    10  UIKit                                0x000000018abf3f64 -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 268
    11  UIKit                                0x000000018ae03a00 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 844
    12  UIKit                                0x000000018ae03eac -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 76
    13  UIKit                                0x000000018ade39f0 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2136
    14  UIKit                                0x000000018ab99508 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 136
```

I've been unable to reproduce this but it's crashing consistently on a number of user devices and there's no common thread between device or OS version except that it's only occurring on iOS 11 and up.

Answer (score 6):

Eventually figured out that this is a bug in `UIKit` when the **Darken Colors** setting is enabled under Accessibility settings:

`Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Increase Contrast -> Darken Colors`

If you're experiencing this crash try toggling that setting on/off to reproduce it.

For now we've suppressed this by simply implementing this method as a `Void` function in an extension:

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
extension UITableViewCell {
  func _setSeparatorDrawsInVibrantLightMode(_ value: Bool) {

  }
}
```

So `UIKit` can call it but it just doesn't do anything (and doesn't crash the app).

Comment: You need to mark the method as @obj in order to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I've got "Invalid redeclaration of '_setSeparatorDrawsInVibrantLightMode'" error in Swift 4.2 for that. Any thoughts?

Comment: looks like that doesn't work for iOS 12. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As jwswart told in his answer next code should be added:

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
extension UITableViewCell {
  @objc func _setSeparatorDrawsInVibrantLightMode(_ value: Bool) {

  }
}
```

But sometimes you receive same error message but for a different problem. To fix it as well, you should add also:

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
extension UITableView {
  @objc func _setSeparatorsDrawInVibrantLightModeUIAppearance(_ value: Bool) {

  }
}
```